# Find string in Python without split?

Tags: python

Purpose of my exercise is to get IP, subnet mask. I wrote my exercise but my teacher said that "Don't use split() to cut and find string. Your code repeat".

This is my code:

```
regex_ip = "(\d{1,3}.){3}\d{1,3}"
dic = {}  
ip = ""
mac = ""
subnet = ""
status = ""
type = ""
list_main = content.split('\n\n')
for i in range(len(list_main)):
    if list_main[i].find("Ethernet") == 0 or list_main[i].find("Wireless")    == 0 :  
    type = list_main[i]
    y = i+1
    list = list_main[y].split("\n")
        for x in range(len(list)):
           if "IPv4" in list[x] or "inet addr" in list[x]:
             strs = re.search(r'{}'.format(regex_ip),list[x])
             ip = strs.group()
           if "Physical" in list[x]:
               strs = re.search(r'([a-zA-Z0-9]{2}-){5}[a-zA-Z0-9]                 {2}',list[x] )
               mac = strs.group()
           if "Subnet" in list[x]:
               strs = re.search(r'{}'.format(regex_ip),list[x])
               subnet = strs.group()
        di = {'ip':ip, 'netmask':subnet, 'mac':mac}
        dic[type] = di 
print dic
```

My content to get IP,subnet:

```
"""Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Windows8_64
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 11:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 1E-55-F9-17-14-BE
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Qualcomm Atheros AR5B97 Wireless Network Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : EC-55-F9-17-14-BE
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::846:7c08:a6b7:c239%16(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.106(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Wednesday, December 30, 2015 7:15:16 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, December 31, 2015 7:15:16 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.100
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.100
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 384587257
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-19-BC-5B-79-00-1E-90-81-D1-14
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 203.113.188.1
                                   203.113.131.3
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadcom NetLink (TM) Gigabit Ethernet
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 1C-75-08-DC-5C-5C
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet1:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-C0-00-01
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::346e:efd2:8d5:b17f%23(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.174.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 352342102
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-19-BC-5B-79-00-1E-90-81-D1-14
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                   fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                   fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:

    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-C0-00-08
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . :   fe80::7ddf:f88d:ff65:b79e%24(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.19.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 369119318
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-19-BC-5B-79-00-1E-90-81-D1-14
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                   fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                   fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Comment: And what is your code?

Comment: Possibly your teacher's idea was to make you think how `split` is actually implemented. Use `[`find`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) or loop over each character 'manually'.

Comment: Feedback on what? This is like asking a mechanic what's wrong with the car you didn't bring to the shop.

Comment: i added my code.my code is woking well but your teacher said your code repeat part of if else command and shouldn't do it and not use split()  @DainDwarf

Comment: my code is above @TigerhawkT3

Comment: thanks for your helping!

Answer (score -1):

You can use **str.find(string_to_search, begin, end)** method.

str is the string where you want to search
string_to_search is the string to be searched
begin is the index the search starts.
end the index the search ends by default is the length of str.

returns the index of the first ocurrence pattern.

Answer (score -2):

ipaddr = "10.10.10.1 255.255.255.0"
import re
ipaddr
'10.10.10.1 255.255.255.0'
x = re.match(r"([0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+) ([0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+)",ipaddr,re.I|re.M)
x.group()
'10.10.10.1 255.255.255.0'
x.group(0)
'10.10.10.1 255.255.255.0'

> > > x.group(1)
> > >       '10.10.10.1'
> > >       x.group(2)
> > >       '255.255.255.0'